# xdocument parsing C# specific fields

Tags: parsing, linq-to-xml

hey guys im trying to parse a xml document . i have attached the xml schema for that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="ArrayOfCourse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Course">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="codeField" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="semesterField" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="titleField" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

im trying to choose the course name, course id, and the semester taught

im lost on how to using choose  specific fields for every course

do i loop through every elements and store those into  strings?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to XML is an easy way to do this.  Let's say you have the following XML:

```
<ArrayOfCourse>
  <Course>
    <codeField>Code 1</codeField>
    <semesterField>Semester 1</semesterField>
    <titleField>Title 1</titleField>
  </Course>
  <Course>
    <codeField>Code 2</codeField>
    <semesterField>Semester 2</semesterField>
    <titleField>Title 2</titleField>
  </Course>
</ArrayOfCourse>
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of work with these course, I'd recommend creating a class to hold the values:

```
public class Course
{

    public string CodeField { get; set; }
    public string SemesterField { get; set; }
    public string TitleField { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can load an XDocument with the XML.  Let's say you have the xml in a file called Courses.xml:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Courses.xml");
```

Now you can use LINQ to XML to create a collection of `Course` objects from the XML:

```
List<Course> courses = (from x in xDoc.Root.Elements("Course")
                       select new Course()
                       {
                           CodeField = (string)x.Element("codeField"),
                           SemesterField = (string)x.Element("semesterField"),
                           TitleField = (string)x.Element("titleField")
                        }).ToList();
```

The above code will give you a `List<Course>` with two items in it.  Each item will have the corresponding `CodeField`, `SemesterField` and `TitleField` values.

The query breaks down as follows:

First, it gets a collection of the "Course" elements (`xDoc.Root.Elements("Course")`).

Next, it takes that collection of "Course" elements and uses the children ("codeField", "semesterField", and "titleField") to instantiate a `Course` object and then converts that collection to a `List<Course>`.

There's lot of information and examples for LINQ to XML and what you can do with it on the web.  Here's the MSDN link to get you started - [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)